# Importar todos los modelos en django

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

Quiero importar todos mis models al archivo admin.py, y cuando lo hago de uno por uno todo bien

```
from .models import doctor,vendedor_farmacia,recepcionista,paciente,horario,usuario,producto,receta,cita,medicamento,venta
```

Pero no me gusta como se ve toda esa linea de codigo, y como voy a usar todos mis modelos, veo que me sirve mucho las siguiente sintaxis

```
from .models import *
```

Sin envargo no me deja hacerlo, me da el siguiente error

*Unused import models from wildcard import*

Comment: puedes hacerlo con `from appname.models import *`

Comment: No es necesario lo del nombre de la app, ya que se encentran en la misma carpeta,

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable es que tengas `Pylint`, que es básicamente un verificador de código fuente, error y sirve para la calidad del lenguaje, en resumen, nos guía a que programemos de forma correcta.

Ahora si bien `from .algo import *` , es totalmente válido para usarse en el lenguaje de Python, también es considerado una mala práctica tal como dice su [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

> Aunque ciertos módulos están diseñados para exportar solo nombres que
>   siguen ciertos patrones cuando se usa `import *`, todavía se considera
>   una mala práctica en el código de producción.

Lo ideal es importarlos todos, nombrándolos a cada uno y obviamente usándolos dentro de nuestro código, para así evitar gastar memoria en algo que no se está usando.

---

Estamos de acuerdo de que el código se ve bastante 'sucio', por así decirlo, importando cada uno de los models por lo mismo se podría:

```
import .models as modelo # sin el from, y así importa todo models
```

Entonces para ocupar algún modelo en particular:

```
modelo.doctor
```

Comment: Pues no puedo jaja, lo dejare así de momento aunque se vea feo, si en algún momento encuentro la respuesta la publicare, pero gracias de igual forma

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que identificar el nombre de tu aplicación por ejemplo:
Si tengo una aplicación que se llama = test

```
   import test.models as model
```

y así por ejemplo para registrarlos a tu admin site:

```
   admin.site.register(model.MiModeloEjemplo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo más óptimo a nivel de programación es que hagas

```
from .models import doctor,vendedor_farmacia,recepcionista,paciente,horario,usuario,producto,receta,cita,medicamento,venta
```

en lugar de esto

```
from .models import *
```

Si quieres ahorrar trabajo o te parece tedioso prueba esta librería [Django Admin Generator](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-generator/) que te genera el admin con sus respectivos campos a partir del models.py y pues te va a resultar más rápido personalizar el admin. Saludos.